# I (Jesus) also will keep you (Philadelphia Church) from the hour of testing.... Rev, 3:10. Keep from *what* exactly?

Tags: john, jesus, revelation

Many a theologian, past and present, will have us believe that the messages to the 7 "First Century" churches are indeed relevant to today's ecclesiology. One would hope, therefore, that we as individuals, are more in line/tune with the ancient church of Philadelphia, for we could very well forgo the ...*hour of testing*, whatever that is. The "general consensus" is that those, of the present day Philadelphian ecclesiology, are to be kept (protected) from the coming, so called, "Great Tribulation", by way of being "raptured" up from the earth and therefore out of harms way, but what if this *idea* is erroneous. For many, the "Great Tribulation" is ancient history, and even happened before the time of John's writing, so maybe our thoughts should be directed elsewhere. When all is said and done, that *hour of testing* is to test all...*those who dwell upon the earth*. The fact that some may well have *already* past a test, of sorts, is immaterial.

**Rev, 3:10, NASB**

> *Because you have kept the word of My perseverance, I also will keep you from the hour of testing, that hour which is about to come upon the whole world, to test those who dwell upon the earth.*

Comment: It has to be observed that the content of what is addressed is addressed to _the angels_ (not, directly, to the church congregations). Until an expositor explains what that really means and how it is applied, one is disinclined to listen to any other comments the expositor might make.

Comment: Very good point!! Had not grasped the fact that the *book* (N-ANS) John was to write and subsequently send to the churches was to be directed to the *angels* of their respective churches and therefore indirectly to the churches - wholly, or proportionately is not made clear. That is so intriguing and for sure needs to be understood before all else. Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

There have been several ways to read and understand the message to the seven churches.  Here is a sample with a focus on The OP's question about "the hour of trial" sentence.

1. **Preterist**

The preterist interpretation believes that the messages to the seven churches were to the seven literal churches in the first century.  Being kept from the hour of trail in this scenario means that their virtue will prevent them entering tribulations of the world.

2. **Spiritual/idealist**

The Idealist approach asserts that these messages are applicable to various classes of people in every age. Being kept from the hour of trial, again is usually interpreted as:

> The promise does not mean the being kept away from, but the being kept
> out from the tribulation. (Ellicott)

or

> In the words κἀγώ σε τηρήσω ἐκ τῆς ὥρας, κ.τ.λ., the church at
> Philadelphia is not promised that it shall be preserved from the hour
> of trial, i.e., that it shall not meet with sufferings full of
> trial,[1465] but in accordance with the presentation of the Apoc.,
> that the troubles before the coming of the Lord will befall all
> believers, who of course are sealed,[1466] lest by the temptation in
> the troubles they may fall;[1467] and in accordance with the
> corresponding expression τηρ. ἐκ,[1468] in distinction from ΤΗΡ.
> ἈΠΌ,[1469] the church at Philadelphia, since it has already maintained
> victorious patience, is also to be delivered by his confirming grace
> from the universal distress impending before the coming of the Lord.
> (Meyer's NT Commentary)

3. **Historical**

One of the main (but not only) understandings of Historicists asserts that the seven churches are seven historical stages during the 2000 years of Christian history.  In this scenario, the Philadelphian church exists prior to the final Laodicean church and is this saved from the great tribulation at the end of time.

4. **Apocalyptic**

The apocalyptic approach is highly varied and far from unified and little consensus exists on how to interpret the seven churches.  Most suggest that all seven churches are seven different churches near the end of time, but how that affects the Philadelphian church is not clear.

5. **Dispensationalist**

Most Dispensationalist interpreters (not all) agree with the Preterist understanding of the seven churches.

For what it is worth, I suggest that more than one of these understandings is correct, but that is another question outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Ok! I get the Preterist view. I follow what Ellicott has said. I cannot however follow Meyer here. I get the Historical and that we are in the Laodicean stage. The "testing" during the Apocalyptic *end times*, I see referring to a "type" of Philadelphian church, and even the Laodicean, but in what manner, is the thing. As for the Dispensationalists, I thought they were all about a future 7 year tribulation - from which they will be excused, at least partially, by way of being raptured - with a "partial" Preterist understanding towards the 7 churches. Your last sentence is telling however, + 1.

Comment: If you just use the internet it will tell you Charles Haden Spurgeon had little to say on escatology and no doubt Jesus was his primary focus, but in sermon 1040 at the last page :Spurgeon in exegesis says he believed the number that no man can count ( Rev. 7: 9-17)  were those saved down through the ages. No pretrib doctrine to that.

Comment: @RHPclass79 - In this case I agree with Spurgeon.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - Dispensationalists are mostly about a future time of trouble etc.  However, they also choose to interpret the seven churches as literal. [Warning: dispensationalism comes in a wide variety of forms.]

Comment: This point could be applicable to all these interpretations; I suggest that the "trial" is a trial of their faith during the times of difficulty, and that the "keeping" promises mean that their faith will be preserved (not necessarily their physical lives).

Comment: @StephenDisraeli - that is a reasonable interpretation (with which I personally agree).

Comment: Excuse me! I misspoke regarding the Dispensationalists having a "partial" Preterist understanding towards the 7 churches. They choose to interpret the seven churches as literal, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

The seven churches represent seven kinds of Christian. It tells what Christian might encounter and what they might become.

1. Ephesus - represent those who become Christian with great passion but later lose their passion somewhere due to earthly desire.
2. Smyrna - represent those who suffer for their faith. Some may give up their faith during the course, but those who persist will receive the victor's crown.
3. Pergamum - represent those who participate in churches of false teaching. Although they claim to be followers of Jesus, they are in danger of losing the salvation.
4. Thyatira - represent liberal Christians who have great love and tolerance to earthly affairs, including harmful influences that contaminate their belief.
5. Sardis - represent hypocritical Christians, who appear to be Christian but are not.
6. Philadelphia - represent faithful Christians who, despite having little strength, are victorious in all kinds of temptation.
7. Laodicea - represent Christians who are satisfied with their present wealth and take their faith too lightly.

Revelation 3:10 NIV

> Since you have kept my command to endure patiently, I will also keep you from the hour of trial that is going to come on the whole world to test the inhabitants of the earth.

In this verse, Jesus affirms their faithfulness, and promise to set them apart from further trials. This is equivalent to the blessing Paul wrote in 1 Thessalonians 5:23

> May God himself, the God of peace, sanctify you through and through. **May your whole spirit, soul and body be kept blameless** at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ. (NIV)

The **'hour of trial'** mentioned in Rev 3:10 does not refer to the End Times. Instead, it is a personal trial that every person experiences during their lifetime. The Lord promises to set apart those who are victorious in their trials and keep them blameless until the end.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, when you say: *It is a revelation to secular churches ...* Thank you for the individual *original* church descriptives, although I was well aware of what they represented and more to boot. I'm more concerned with what the *hour of testing* could "actually" be about with regard to our present day churches. It goes without saying that the unbelievers of this world are going to have a hard time.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - I edit my answer and hopefully its clarity is better.

Comment: Ok, better. But I cannot agree with your newly worded last paragraph, as it *has to* refer to the "End Times", if only for the fact that it speaks of the *whole world* being subjected.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - my point of view is each church is an allusion to one kind of Christian. Trials can only applicable to us during our lifetime. Therefore I don't think that it refers to the 'End Times'. Surely my argument is valid only if my previous assumption is true.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unlike the letters to the first three churches, the last four letters all include an explicit reference to the second coming of Christ, which of course includes the letter to the church of Philadelphia and is that which **Rev, 3:10** refers to, therefore the *second* fulfillment of the prophecy ( *first* being to the 1st Century fulfillment) is still yet future and therefore within the "End Times". Full Preterists, however, are of the believe that Christ's second coming happened at the time of the first fulfillment, I think through a misapplication of the "Transfiguration".

Comment: Ignore my last sentence. Full Preterists are of the believe that Christ's second coming came at the time of the Roman destruction of Jerusalem in 70 AD, wherein all eschatological or "End Times" events were fulfilled, including the resurrection of the dead and Jesus' Second Coming, or Parousia, and the Final Judgement even. If, however, by the time the *futuristic* believe in the "End Times" conclude but many have already lived their lives, then I agree - judgement will be based on how they coped under trial in their lifetimes.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - you may notice that I am not based on any existing theories. When there are many interpretations from notable people, it raises the question of who got the spirit inspiration. It may suggest that the truth is still hidden. I don't mean to have found the truth, I just provide one perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe that the first premise to use is to keep in prayer and when studying scriptures daily ALWAYS ASK the Holy Spirit to guide and teach us the word He inspired.
I feel like majority tend to rely on theologians and scholars blindly, though I do not take lightly the truth that there are those servants anointed by Christ to share scriptural truth.
Ephesians 4:11-16

Comment: If you haven't taken the Biblical Hermeneutics tour (see below) and checked out the Code of Conduct, you should, to see what we are all about. Your answer, while noteworthy, does not go to the "nuts and bolts" of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Careful hermeneutics requires considering and analyzing a section of the biblical text in context from several perspectives.

Here, John the Revelator has clearly recorded short critiques addressed to seven assemblies (*ekklésia*) rather than individuals. The distinction becomes excruciatingly obvious in several places including Revelation 2:14, 15 ESV where Jesus states:

> “But I have a few things against you: you have **some** there who hold the
> teaching of Balaam, who taught Balak to put a stumbling block before
> the sons of Israel, so that they might eat food sacrificed to idols
> and practice sexual immorality. So also you have **some** who hold the
> teaching of the Nicolaitans.”

Jesus says these are assemblies of believers and directs some of his comments at specific subgroups or individuals within these assemblies.

It’s also important to note that there were more than seven churches at that time. Strong evidence presents itself in the fact that the major churches during John’s time are missing from the list, namely Jerusalem, Alexandria, Antioch, Byzantium, and Rome.

Also, "the seven churches in Asia" (or Anatolia, roughly modern-day Turkey) should have included Colossae as well as others mentioned in the book of Acts. Galatia is a region in Anatolia that includes the towns of Antioch, Iconium, Lystra, and Derbe. Antioch of Syria was the third largest city in the Roman Empire after Rome and Alexandria, and played a significant role in Acts.

Surely, Jesus should have mentioned Antioch. Also, the apostle Paul wrote important letters to the Galatians and to the Colossians. Jesus didn't mention these. So, it doesn't seem unreasonable that Jesus had archetypes mind.

Some Christians believe that these archetypes exist throughout the church age but also represent prevalent archetypes during the different chronological periods of the church.

Jesus indicates that the assembly at Smyrna will need to endure **ten days** of persecution (note that the most severe persecution occurred during the reign of ten Roman emperors). The assembly at Pergamum was also persecuted and Antipas was martyred there. However, the assembly at Philadelphia would be kept from (a) **the hour** of trial coming upon (b) **the whole world**.

In context with the rest of Revelation, it's not speculative that what follows represents the hour of trial coming on **the whole world**, namely the great tribulation where much of the world is destroyed. The rest of the book of Revelation
documents this destruction.

However, Revelation does not specify *how* the assembly at Philadelphia would be spared. One needs to reference other passages in scripture for this promise.

Comment: I agree that it's not speculative that what follows represents trials and tribulations coming on **the whole world**, some of which will be great, the likes of which have probably been playing out ever since 1914 most probably. I just feel like the modern day equivalent of the Church of Philadelphia gets to be spared from something more specific and of a much shorter duration, that is within the so called "Great Tribulations" period. BTW, I have never been an advocate for a "7 year" tribulation period, to supposedly encompass Daniel's 70th week, as IMO that's dispensationalist nonsense.